# Database visualization tool

Tags: database, entity-framework, entity

I just watched a session of PDC09 about new features of Entity framework in .NET 4.

Video page: http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT10

in the video, (seek to minute 7) presenter used a database visualzation tool to open table and view data.

Does anyone know what's the name of it and where I can download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [Microsoft Quadrant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd857506(VS.85).aspx). I believe he says it in the video as well.